# Graph in ToolTips on a map control

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-map

I have created an SSRS report with a Map control. I have a tooltip for each state in the map. I want to show a graph in the tooltip.

Is it possible to show a graph in a tooltip? If so kindly let me know the steps to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in any version of SSRS.  Tooltips are limited to text.  I would explore using an Action to link to another report that shows the graph.